# Android 3d layout rotation animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-animation

I need to have a 3d rotating animation when start a new activity. It should me looks like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5b0EKUU3h4&feature=player_embedded) But here it use two image views. I need to have animation between two layouts.

Thanks in advance !